# How to trigger ng-change when testing with $componentController?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

*Edit: this question is for Angular 1.5.7.*

I am testing my component with `$componentController` and I want to test that the "&" binding gets invoked on a model change.

```
const component = {
    bindings: {
        myModel: '<',
        onChange: '&'
    }
}
```

The component uses `ng-change` in the template to handle any model changes:

```
<select ng-model="vm.myModel"
        ng-change="vm.handleMyModel()">
    ...
</select>
```

Inside the component controller, `handleMyModel` does some stuff and finally invokes the callback.

```
handleMyModel() {
   ...doStuff
   this.onChange();
}
```

However, when I run this code in the test, the `handleMyModel` function never gets called.

```
const bindings = {
    myModel: 'thanks for reading',
    onChange: function() {}
};
spyOn(bindings, 'onChange');

const vm = $componentController('myComponent', {}, bindings);
vm.$onInit();
vm.myModel = 'hello world'; // I want this reassignment to trigger handleMyModel();

expect(bindings.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How can I trigger the function passed into ng-change when I change the model through `$componentController`?

Should I be testing the DOM element directly with $compile? And then finding the option item and triggering a 'change' event? (This approach seems messier than changing the model in $componentController.)

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used `$componentController` (we test everything through the view), but it looks as though you're just testing the controller and not the view.  Therefore, there is nothing saying to the controller to execute the `handleMyModel` function when the binding changes.  You'll need to call that function manually in the test.

Comment: @Sophie That makes sense, but it is unfortunate!. So if you were writing this test for the view, is it okay to have jasmine code that is dependent on the DOM structure? For example, in this case I would have to find the second `option` element and trigger a change event. Where do you draw the line on being overly dependent on CSS classes and HTML structure? Perhaps that's another question entirely.

Comment: If you're testing it through the view (using `angular.element('<my-component my-model="$scope.myModel" />)`), you shouldn't need to trigger the change event manually (although you may need to call `$scope.$apply()`) when you change `$scope.myModel`.